How to use WidgetConfiguration.promptsForUserConfiguration() with a deployment target earlier than iOS 18
I've implemented my widget configuration like so in my app that supports iOS 17+
@main
struct MyWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "MyWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: MyIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
                MyEntryView(entry: entry)
            }
            .configurationDisplayName("Display Name")
            .description("Description")
            .promptsForUserConfiguration()
        } else {
            AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: MyIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
                MyEntryView(entry: entry)
            }
            .configurationDisplayName("Display Name")
            .description("Description")
        }
    }
}

This results in a compile-time error

Branches have mismatching types 'some WidgetConfiguration' (result of 'Self.promptsForUserConfiguration()') and 'some WidgetConfiguration' (result of 'Self.description')

How are you supposed to use this when you can't change the deployment target to iOS 18?

Same issue here, this is maddening.
I wonder whether that's a bug in the Beta, because other modifiers that are applied conditionally based on iOS version (for example contentMarginsDisabled()) do not trigger this underlying type change.

You can create two different Widgets and move the availability check up to the body of your WidgetBundle.

Add a WidgetBundle if you don't have one already
Remove @main from your Widget if you did not have a WidgetBundle
Duplicate your Widget and rename it
Add @available(iOS 18.0, *) to the widget that contains .promptsForUserConfiguration()

@main
struct MyAppWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            return MyWidget()
        } else {
            return MyLegacyWidget()
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 18.0, *)
struct MyWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "MyWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: MyIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            MyEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Display Name")
        .description("Description")
        .promptsForUserConfiguration()
    }
}

struct MyLegacyWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "MyWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: MyIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            MyEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Display Name")
        .description("Description")
    }
}


Originally left a comment, but formatting was incorrect. Left my comment as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79008277/4027606

FYI, you can't have an else block in the body of WidgetBundle, based on how WidgetBundleBuilder is implemented (source).
What I discovered is that you can return two widgets that share the same attributes type, and only the first one that applies will be used. This means that the below code is still safe for iOS 18+, and you won't have two Live Activities started.
@main
struct MyAppWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            MyWidget()
        }
        MyLegacyWidget()
    }
}


Create a wrapping function that handles checking version availability:
extension WidgetConfiguration {
    func promptsForConfiguration() -> some WidgetConfiguration {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 18.0, *) {
            return self.promptsForUserConfiguration()
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}

And call that function instead.

It is also worth nothing that currently, implicit returns cannot yet be used here due to this open issue in the Swift language.
